# create sagemaker notebook instance via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sagemaker

I am taking my first steps into the Terraform world so please be gentle with me. I have a user with AmazonSageMakerFullAccess, which I stored via AWS CLI in a profile called terraform. I can create an S3 bucket as follows no problem referring this user in Windows in VSC:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
    shared_credentials_files = ["C:\\Users\\amazinguser\\.aws\\credentials"]
    profile = "terraform"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "blabla-test-bucket"

  tags = {
    Name        = "amazing_tag"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

I try to implement [this](https://github.com/dkhundley/terraform-sagemaker-tutorial/tree/main/Part%202a%20-%20Creating%20a%20SageMaker%20Notebook) documented [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/terraform-sagemaker-part-2a-creating-a-custom-sagemaker-notebook-instance-1d68c90b192b) and try to this:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" "notebook_instance" {
  name = "titanic-sagemaker-byoc-notebook"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.notebook_iam_role.arn
  instance_type = "ml.t2.medium"
  #lifecycle_config_name = aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance_lifecycle_configuration.notebook_config.name
  #default_code_repository = aws_sagemaker_code_repository.git_repo.code_repository_name
}
```

I am a bit confused about the role_arn which is defined here:

https://github.com/dkhundley/terraform-sagemaker-tutorial/blob/main/Part%202a%20-%20Creating%20a%20SageMaker%20Notebook/terraform/iam.tf

Can I not use the above user? Thanks!

Comment: The user is one part of the story, most of the services in AWS (including SageMaker) have something called execution role. The execution role is needed to perform actions of behalf of SageMaker in the background, i.e., to perform tasks you are unaware of but the notebook needs to be able to perform them.

Comment: thanks but would sagemaker not use the user specified in the profile terraform with for example AmazonSageMakerFullAccess which the user has?

Comment: You mean the credentials you provide to Terraform?

Comment: yes ... so is all this:

https://github.com/dkhundley/terraform-sagemaker-tutorial/blob/main/Part%202a%20-%20Creating%20a%20SageMaker%20Notebook/terraform/iam.tf

independent/for sagemaker only?

Comment: The credentials you are using to run Terraform are used exactly for that: to allow Terraform to perform API calls from the CLI. The role from the URL you sent is used as an execution role for SageMaker. You could in theory create a role that would be used to run Terraform and SageMaker, but I would strongly advise against it. Try to honour the principle of least privilege as much as possible.

Comment: that makes sense now. sorry about my ignorance. so no "user" created for sagemaker "only" execution roles?

Comment: Well, there are no users for SageMaker notebooks, however if you ever start using SageMaker Studio there will be users. These users also assign execution roles to their environments. In short, for your use case: no users, one execution role with proper permissions assigned. Role is another AWS IAM resource you are creating with Terraform. You can check the resource that was created in IAM  service UI in AWS console.

Comment: please fee free to post as answer or I can delete question

Comment: I will try to add an answer and encompass everything that needs to be said. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS services trying to call other AWS services and perform actions are not allowed to do so by default. For example, SageMaker Notebooks are basically EC2 instances. In order for SageMaker to create EC2 instances, it has to have a policy which allows e.g., injecting ENIs to a VPC. Since you probably do not want to do all that by yourself (it is a managed Notebook service after all), you have to give SageMaker permissions to perform actions on your behalf. Enter **execution roles**. For SageMaker, you can read more in [1]. Other services that you will commonly find using execution roles are Lambda, ECS and many others. An IAM role usually consists of two parts:

1. Trust relationship (I like to call it trust policy)
2. Permissions policy

The first one decides which principal (AWS identifier, Service etc. [2]) will be able to assume the role. In your example, that is:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sm_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["sagemaker.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

What this policy says is "I am going to allow SageMaker (which is of type `Service`) to assume any role to which this policy is attached and perform actions that are defined in the permissions policy". The permissions policy is:

```
# Attaching the AWS default policy, "AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "sm_full_access_attach" {
  name = "sm-full-access-attachment"
  roles = [aws_iam_role.notebook_iam_role.name]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
}
```

Without going into too much details about what the AWS managed policy for SageMaker does, it is enough to see the `FullAccess` part for it to be clear. What you could do if you want to be extra careful is to define a customer managed policy [3] for SageMaker notebooks. This permissions policy will be attached to the IAM role(s) defined in the `roles` argument. Note that it is a list, so multiple roles can have the same permissions policy attached.

Last, but not the least, the glue between the trust and permissions policy is the role itself:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "notebook_iam_role" {
  name = "sm_notebook_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sm_assume_role_policy.json
}
```

As you can see, the `assume_role_policy` is the policy which will allow SageMaker to perform actions in the AWS account based on the permissions defined in the permissions policy.

This topic is much more complex than in this answer, but it should give you a fair amount of information.

NOTE: In theory, the same role accessing information in AWS and running the AWS API actions when using Terraform could be used for SageMaker, but I would strongly advise against it. Always keep in mind separation of concerns and principle of least privilege.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html#sagemaker-roles-create-execution-role

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/authen-custmanagedpolicies.html